# How to add a class to body tag?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to a body tag with jQuery.

For example if the URL is http://www.mywebsite.com/about_us.asp, I want add the first five letters, in this case 'about', to the body tag:

```
<body class="about">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var newClass = window.location.href;
newClass = newClass.substring(newClass.lastIndexOf('/')+1, 5);
$('body').addClass(newClass);
```

The whole "five characters" thing is a little worrisome; that kind of arbitrary cutoff is usually a red flag. I'd recommend catching everything until an _ or .:

```
newClass = newClass.match(/\/[^\/]+(_|\.)[^\/]+$/);
```

That pattern should yield the following:

- `../about_us.html` : about
- `../something.html` : something
- .`./has_two_underscores.html` : has

Comment: more effective than $('body') is $(document.body), avoids the selector process. See http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector (note: 'higher is better' in given stats)

Comment: $(document.body) works with jQuery 1.9.0 as well (while $("body") doesn't work (tested in Chrome)).

Comment: Oh thank you I was trying to do that and it wasn't working but you saved me :)

Answer (score 22):

Use:

```
$(document.body).addClass('about');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('body').toggleClass("className");
```

perfectly works

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract that part of the URL using a simple [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
var url = location.href;
var className = url.match(/\w+\/(\w+)_/)[1];
$('body').addClass(className);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're going to want `document.location`. Do some sort of string manipulation on it (unless jQuery has a way to avoid that work for you) and then

```
$(body).addClass(foo);
```

I know this isn't the complete answer, but I assume you can work the rest out :)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this might work:

```
$("body").attr("class", "about");
```

It uses jQuery's `attr()` to add the class *'about'* to the body.

Comment: This works fine for adding a class to the body.  Just didn't answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem,

```
<body id="body">
```

Add an ID tag to the body:

```
$('#body').attr('class',json.class); // My class comes from Ajax/JSON, but change it to whatever you require.
```

Then switch the class for the body's using the id. This has been tested in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), Internet Explorer, and [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29).