# Change background using a link's class

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

First, sorry for my English, I'm French, so..

Here is my problem. 
I have a menu, with a class="selected" for active item. And I have a custom css for this class. It works, so, it's ok for this.
But, I'd like to have a different body's background for pages.
For exemple, the page1 must be gray, the page2 black, etc..

But, I can't add a class to my body (And then, change background with css), because I load all the pages into the same index.php file.

I thought that I could solve my problem with a bit of javascript? Which will get which item has the "selected" class, and apply a custom body's background

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

There can be a lot of other different ways to do that. here is one idea.

On Page load using Jquery's $(document).get ready, you can get the selected menu. Here is a rough idea about the whole.

```
<ul>
<li bodybgcolor="red" class="selected"></li>
<li bodybgcolor="green"></li>
<li bodybgcolor="yell"></li>
<ul>

 $(document).ready(function() { 
 bodybgcolor =   $(.selected).attr("bodybgcolor");
 $("body").css('background-color', 'blue');
 }
```

you can get the class=selected and its bodybgcolor attribute to set the body color.

**From Server Side :**
If you are dynamically generating the menus and flagging the selected class at them , then at that time you defined a body bg color in a $bodybgcolor and can use the same in your body color or in styling.

```
<body background=""=<?php  echo $bodybgcolor; ?>>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i'll try and i'll say you the result

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I tried your solution, and I think that I made something wrong. When you say "...to set the body color", what should I do exactly? I'm learning javascript right now, so, I don't how to do exactly

Comment: I just see what you add (the 5 last lines). Can you be more precise? How could I style body using $bodybgcolor

Comment: It doesn't work. I checked Safari's inspector, and there is an error. I don't know what kind, but it said "Syntax error:Unexpected token"

Comment: It simply explains that there is some sytax error. Dont copy and paste. Just get an idea from the above and use it your own way.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try to better understand your code and come back when i'll get some results. Thanks for all, and sorry for my ignorance ;)

Comment: I found maybe a better idea, I could add a class with the url.
All my links give me a domain.me/#page1
So, I could get the "page1" in the url et use it as a class name for the body tag

This guy has this kind of problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283511/how-to-add-a-class-to-body-tag

I tried the solution but it doesn't work, I don't understand what should I change to make it work

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery:

```
$("#id_of_what_you_want_to_change).css({background: url("image.jpg")});
```

of for every page:

On page load do this, assuming you have a series of images for background each with the name of the corresponding page:

```
 jQuery(function($){
var title = $(this).attr('title');

        loadbackground(title);      
    });
function loadbackground(title)
{
$("body").css({background: url(title+".jpg")});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set a color et not an image, so it doesn't really fit, right?

Comment: well you can use any css inside the css tag so it should work, but I hope you already found a solution

Comment: Try to add this script at the beginning of the page: jQuery(function($){$("body").css({ background:#ffffff });

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and I'll tell you the result. Unfortunatly, I didn't found a solution yet

Comment: Just to be sure, line4, you wrote: "backfround", it's "background" right?

Comment: Indra, your solution works, but I have an other problem. I built my website with this: http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

If you try this here: http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp You see that url changes, but the page doesn't reload.

Comment: So, when I click on the links of my menu, (you can see my website here:http://fabienlefrapper.me/effeleffe/), the background doesn't change. And, when I go for example, from the "Prestations" page to the "Travail" page, the background doesn't change. But when I reload the page, it changes.

An idea to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: the only solution i can think about now, though I'm not sure it will work is to add the script in the page loader.php so that it loads along with the page contents. I had a similar problem a while ago, but with pictures and I remember I solved it adding a delay, but I don't think this is what you're looking for. This is what i did then: setTimeout('getPictureList(project, current_page)',25); where getPictureList was my function