# Add a Class to Body Tag: Testing Existing Javascript Solution with No Results

Tags: jquery, html

I found a great piece of Javascript code **(StackOverflow link: [How to add a class to body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283511/how-to-add-a-class-to-body-tag))**. However, I am having trouble implementing it.

Below is the code I'm using on a test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var newClass = window.location.href;
newClass = newClass.match(/\/[^\/]+(_|\.)[^\/]+$/);
$(document.body).addClass(newClass);
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However I do not see any class added to the body tag as a result. (Viewing Source in Safari, Chrome) I've tested with and without jQuery.

Do you see what's wrong with the code?

I'm working with a Behance ProSite. I can create multiple galleries, but each will have the same background because they use the same template. I need to add a unique class to the body tag so I can target each with a different CSS background property.

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included on your page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've added `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` and replaced the last line of Javascript with `$('body').addClass(newClass);` and still no results.

Comment: You should reference jquery *before* the your script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple minor issues with this code:

1. Make sure the regex in `match` actually matches your URL patterns. I think Behance Prosites use a URL pattern like `/1234/section` and `/1234/5678/section/item`.
2. The `match` function returns an array, so you can't pass `newClass` directly into `addClass`. You need to pass one of the array items, like `newClass[0]`.
3. Since your script is in the `<head>` it can't modify `<body>` because it doesn't exist at execution time. You either need to move the script to the bottom of the page or defer execution until after the DOM is loaded.

This snippet should work specifically for Behance Prosites. The regex matches URL path segments with at least one non-numeric character, to filter out the `/1234/5678/` from the URL, so `newClass[0]` will be `section` in the above example URLs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var newClass = path.match(/[^\/]*[^\d\/][^\/]*/);
  $('body').addClass(newClass[0]);
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 21):

To add a class to the body tag, you can do the following in vanilla Javascript without the need to include some fat 3rd party library

If a class already exists on the body then

```
document.body.className += " something";
```

Otherwise

```
document.body.className = "something";
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/syAAp/)

To have the class added after the page has finished loading then use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) and create a handler for the [window.onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.body.className = "something";
}, false);
```

Comment: Makes sense, but still not working for me (Chrome & Safari), this is the code I'm using line for line in case I'm missing something: `<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.className = "something";
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: Implement the onload listener like I demonstrated in my example.

Comment: To remove classname in modern browsers, you can use 
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('something');
The classname is case sensitive